# Animate NavigationController transition without animating navigation bar

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, ios6

I have a typical ios app with a navigationcontroller. The navigation bar on the top has left and right buttons that stay the same through different views, so I would like to animate just the current view and not the top bar.

I'm not sure how to get started with this.

Comment: You can create a customviewcontroller with a toolbar at the top of the screen and subclass this viewcontroller to create your viewcontrollers. Make sure you have hidden the navigationbar in this case and push the viewcontrollers. Only problem is you have to code for the back button functionality here.

Comment: What animations are you trying to avoid? The back button animations?

Answer (score 0):

I've got an idea.
First, add your custom navigation bar on the top of the main view.
Second, add a navigationController as a subview under your navigation bar.
Now if the navigationController do the pushing or popping, your navigation bar will not change at all.